# Como recuperar datos de Database Realtime Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

estoy intentándo recuperar datos de firebase Realtime y me sale null. No encuentro la lógica, ¿podrían orientarme? Gracias

mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        obtenerLondres=(TextView)findViewById( R.id.obtenerLondres );

```
    mDatabase.child( "Londres" ).child( "Clientes" ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String nombre = dataSnapshot.child( "nombre" ).getValue( String.class );
                String telefono = dataSnapshot.child( "telefono" ).getValue( String.class );
                String email = dataSnapshot.child( "email" ).getValue( String.class );
                String personas = dataSnapshot.child( "personas" ).getValue( String.class );

                obtenerLondres.setText( "NOMBRE   : " + nombre   + "\n" + "\n" + "EMAIL    :   " + email + "\n" + "\n" +
                                        "TELÉFONO : " + telefono + "\n" + "\n" + "PERSONAS :   " + personas );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Fallo de lectura de datos: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
```

Mi BD:

```
proyectoapp-2f820 Londres
```

Londres

Clientes

"Comida      :  ":

"Email       :  ":

"Entradas    :  ":

"Excursiones :  ":

"Personas    :  ":

"Telefono    :  ":

"Transporte  :  ":

"nombre      :  ":

---

Gracias amigo Gastón por contestar, sigue sin darme el resultado esperado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando haces getValue

```
String nombre = dataSnapshot.child( "nombre" ).getValue( String.class );
                String telefono = dataSnapshot.child( "telefono" ).getValue( String.class );
                String email = dataSnapshot.child( "email" ).getValue( String.class );
                String personas = dataSnapshot.child( "personas" ).getValue( String.class );
```

Fijate que estas haciendo `.child("")` con nombres que no coinciden con tu base de datos, cambialos a los siguiente

```
String nombre = dataSnapshot.child( "nombre" ).getValue( String.class );
                String telefono = dataSnapshot.child( "Telefono" ).getValue( String.class );
                String email = dataSnapshot.child( "Email" ).getValue( String.class );
                String personas = dataSnapshot.child( "Personas" ).getValue( String.class );
```